# Solving vector equation 2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

> Using vector method, show that the vector equation 
>   $$\bar{x}\times \bar{a}+(\bar{x}.\bar{b})\bar{c}=\bar{d}$$
>   is satisfied if $$\bar{x}=\lambda \bar{a}+\bar{a}\times \frac{\bar{a}\times (\bar{d}\times \bar{c})}{(\bar{a}.\bar{c}){a^2}}$$

**Attempt**

Taking dot product by $\bar{a}$

$0+(\bar{x}.\bar{b})(\bar{a}.\bar{c})=(\bar{a}.\bar{d})$

i.e 
$\bar{x}.\bar{b}=\frac{\bar{a}.\bar{d}}{\bar{a}.\bar{c}}$

Let $p=\frac{\bar{a}.\bar{d}}{\bar{a}.\bar{c}}$

Then $\bar{x}.\bar{b}=p =p \frac{\bar{b}.\bar{b}}{|\bar{b}|^2} \implies \left(x-p\frac{\bar{b}}{|\bar{b}|^2}\right).\bar{b}=0$

Its general solution is $\bar{x}=p\frac{\bar{b}}{|\bar{b}|^2}+\bar{t}\times \bar{b}=\frac{\bar{a}.\bar{d}}{\bar{a}.\bar{c}}\frac{\bar{b}}{|\bar{b}|^2}+\bar{t}\times \bar{b}$ where $\bar{t}$ is any vector.

Please help. My solution is not desired.

Comment: Independent of $\mathbf{b}$?

Comment: @NgChungTak I have written as it is. Would you please suggest how to get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $\mathbf{a \times x} =\mathbf{u} \implies \displaystyle
> \mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{a}-\frac{\mathbf{a\times u}}{a^2}
> $

Now,

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{a\times x} &=(\mathbf{x\cdot b}) \mathbf{c-d} \\
  &= \frac{\mathbf{a\cdot d}}{\mathbf{a\cdot c}} \mathbf{c-d} \\
  &= \frac{(\mathbf{a\cdot d})\mathbf{c}-(\mathbf{a\cdot c})\mathbf{d}}
          {\mathbf{a\cdot c}} \\
  &= -\frac{\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{d\times c})}
           {\mathbf{a\cdot c}} \\
\end{align*}

Can you proceed?

Comment: yes. thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1942348, you can further breakdown $\mathbf{x}$ into $\displaystyle \mu \mathbf{a}-\frac{\mathbf{d\times c}}{\mathbf{a\cdot c}}$ where $\displaystyle \mu=\lambda+\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot (\mathbf{d\times c})}{(\mathbf{a\cdot c})a^2}$, so $\displaystyle \mathbf{x\cdot b}=\mu \mathbf{a\cdot b}-\frac{\mathbf{b\cdot d\times c}}{\mathbf{a\cdot c}}$, hence $\displaystyle \mu=\frac{\mathbf{a\cdot d}+\mathbf{b\cdot d\times c}}{(\mathbf{a\cdot b})(\mathbf{a\cdot c})}$